# Need a port map solution for Linux

Tags: linux, networking

AnalogX makes a handy useful Windows utility named Portmapper. It listens on any ports you like and forwards traffic to another IP address. So you can open a range of ports in your router, all mapped to one machine. That machine then forwards each specific port to any address you like within the LAN.

This is a good solution for routers with a limited number of NAT entries available. Just point a range to a single PC and let it do the rest. It can forward port 80 traffic to 192.168.1.101, port 5900 to 192.168.1.102, and port 5901 to 192.168.1.103:5900, etc.

I'm looking for a linux-based replacement. Either a program where I create a config file detailing the port numbers and IPs to forward, or a strategy to use a built-in solution like iptables. Any suggestions on how to do this?

Comment: You posted to the wrong site. Stack Overflow is for *programming* questions. If you are a professional sysadmin you probably want [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/), otherwise [Super User](http://superuser.com/). This question might get automatically migrated when it is closed, if not you probably want to search first.

Comment: I wasn't aware of those sites because the majority of my searches are programming related and always take me to this site. I will use them for any future non-programming topics.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can do that natively in Linux with `iptables`:

http://www.debuntu.org/how-to-redirecting-network-traffic-a-new-ip-using-iptables

http://ramblings.narrabilis.com/ip-forward-using-iptables-port-and-host-redirect

http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/nat.html

Comment: The first link was exactly what I needed and worked right off the bat. Thanks.